# What is the mime type for ashx

Tags: iis-7, mime

I am trying to move a legacy app to iis7. I have found hundreds of posts on how to setup mime types, but not one on what exaclty the mime type for .ashx is.

Also, I don't understand how aspx is being served by iis7 and it does not list it as a mime type. I check the iis6 box the legacy code is coming from (where it works), and there is not one single mime type listed at all.

Comment: Have you actually enabled ASP.NET / .NET Framework? (It's in "Features" on the Server Manager Page)

Comment: Yes, 3.5.1 is installed and enabled under features. Is this 4.x ? This site is currently serving up aspx and asmx (wcf also installed). I don't get how the mime tipes for those are not listed.

Comment: The MIME type is not listed because this is not a filetype which gets "served" directly. Only types of files which get served directly from the filesystem to the client are listed. (like .jpg)
You should find .aspx and .ashx on `"Handler Mappings"` in IIS7

Comment: Have you added ASP.NET in the IIS Server Role? (Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Server (IIS) -> Add Role Services -> ASP.NET)

Comment: Ok, see them, and they all appear to be setup and enabled (6 of them for .ashx). So I guess my problem is actualy why are they not being served. Fiddler shows the server is not responding for any .ashx request.

Comment: What does your browser show when you hit an ASHX page? IIS should at least respond to the request with an error... ?

Comment: IIS responds with 'resource cannot be found'. When I use the same url on the iis 6 box that is working, it returns javascript for this ... legacy app I know little about.

Comment: Michael, thanks ... it is under handler mappings, as you said. Starting another thread, as I misunderstood my own problem. Thanks